# C# Passing cast arrays to receiver of array of dynamic type array

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, types

Okay, so I had something working at one point, but all my old test code has been accidentally deleted, and I can't get this working again...  Help!

I have a function in a library:

```
public int SetData( dynamic[] p_a )
    {
    int successful_count = 0;
    int _save_selected_row;

    //It goes on...
    }
```

The users will call this function, and I thought I remembered it being called this way:

```
    struct MyStruct
        {
        public String Name;
        public String Home_Address;
        }
    MyStruct[] UseArray = new MyStruct[2];



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        UseArray[0].Name = "Override name 1";
        UseArray[0].Home_Address = "Override address 1";
        UseArray[1].Name = "Override name 2";
        UseArray[1].Home_Address = "Override address 2";

        ncflsDisplay1.SetData( UseArray );
        }
```

But I get the error "Cannot convert from MyStruct[] to dynamic[]".

Same error for

```
ncflsDisplay1.SetData( (dynamic[]) UseArray );
```

I know I had something like this working a month ago, but in a code clean-up, my test programs got deleted.

Any idea what the call the user will need to make would have to look like to call "SetData" with an array of whatever type they have?

Update:
Got it working with this monstrosity, but I know I didn't have to do this before...

```
 UseArray.Cast<dynamic>().ToArray()
```

There was much cleaner code at one point - like a simple call using UseArray, but that doesn't work now.

Marked as duplicate because the one who marked it says we should use classes instead of structures, and using classes to pass objects of subclasses is well documented. While the suggestion is well intentioned, it is not applicable here.

First solution has been overtaken by events. We have a newer solution!

Changed the parameters of the display function to

```
 public int SetData<T>( T[] p_a )
```

which allows a call by the user of

```
ncflsDisplay1.SetData( UseArray );
```

Comment: You should not be using `dynamic` for something like that.  Use interfaces to perform an operation on any number of different types with that operation.  `MyStruct` also shouldn't be a struct, given that it's a mutable type.  It should be a class, or at a minimum, be immutable (but even then it has no good reason to be a `struct`).

Comment: Well, it's not mutable so far as I am aware. The user has some (very small) amount of data grouped logically which I must display.They have their structures, they throw them to me.  I don't believe we're interested in making classes for each little line to be displayed in a grid, so the link (duplicate) to this other one you pointed out does not apply. Neither does your suggestion that one or two fields of data be turned into a full blown class.  I mean, I see where you're coming from, and if it were larger and more complex, I'd agree, but it's just not.

Comment: Yes, it is mutable.  You may not be mutating it (in which case, all the more reason to change the type to be immutable), but it can be mutated.  Why are you opposed to using a class here?  Why would that be a problem?  The duplicate *absolutely* answers your question.  It explains precisely why it isn't working and what you can do about it.  The rest is up to you.

Comment: For the record, the expense of using `dynamic` is, first off all, forcing the object to be a class, not a value type, due to it's very nature, and is also *many orders of magnitude* more expensive, in addition to being extremely unsafe and not at all appropriate to the situation.

Comment: Well, perhaps we will revisit our thinking on what we're trying to accomplish.  Our intention was just to transfer small blocks of logically grouped data from an array of items to a displayer.  We had thought to use small, locally defined structures, rather than creating and filling classes/objects. The List version seems to work well, and appears quick - we needed an array version since that's the way the data is actually stored upstream.  Thank you for your suggestion, and I'll update this post if we change our minds.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use that function and can't update its signature, you can try copying the array:

```
MyStruct[] UseArray = new MyStruct[2];

dynamic[] newArr = new dynamic[UseArray.Length];

Array.Copy(UseArray, newArr, UseArray.Length);

SetData(newArr);
```

Otherwise you can change it to something like `SetData<T>(T data)` or SetData(object data)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we're moving forward with this, even though I *know* I didn't have to do this before.

```
UseArray.Cast<dynamic>().ToArray()
```

Newer solution: See end of the edited question, but basically it's now

```
public int SetData<T>( T[] p_a )
```

so the call is a simple

```
ncflsDisplay1.SetData( UseArray );
```

Comment: Actually it's: UseArray.Cast<dynamic>().ToArray().  I don't know why the word "dynamic" isn't showing up in the answer - it's there...